# Call Python class instance function from Java

Tags: python, java, jython

Python code

```
class TestClass(object):
    def TestFunc(self):
        print("TestFunc!")

_test_class = TestClass()

def TestFunc():
    _test_class.TestFunc()
```

Java code

```
public static void Main(String[] args){
    PythonInterpreter pi = new PythonInterpreter();

    // Execute python code here using pi.execfile() or pi.exec()

    PyObject testClass = pi.get("_test_class");
    // testClass is successfully obtained
   
    // <- Answer goes here    
}
```

So, here's my question. Can and, if so, how do I call TestFunc() on the TestClass instance I retrieved from the Python interpreter?

I can easily get the non-class TestFunc function from the interpreter
`PyObject func = pi.get("TestFunc")` and then call it 'func.__ call __()' so that's one solution but I'd prefer to call a function directly on the instance.

So, questions are:

1. How can I directly call a class instance function once I've retrieved the instance?
2. If 1 isn't possible, can I retrieve a PyObject representing the function from the instance and call that? If yes, how? Will it be called on the instance it was retrieved from?
3. If neither 1 nor 2, what's the way to do this? Is a module-level "wrapper" function like TestFunc() the only way?

Comment: I think you're looking for `testClass.invoke("TestFunc")`

Comment: @ElliottFrisch You are absolutely correct! Any chance you know of an invoke that will take Java objects like _jcall does? I will need to pass complex Java objects as arguments. Please add your reply as an answer so I can accept it.